# TypeScript type declarations for "package.json" manifest file?

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings, package.json, type-declaration

What would be the best way to type the contents of the "package.json" manifest file in TypeScript?

```typescript
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

export function loadManifest(): Promise<any> {

  const manifestPath = `${PROJECT_DIR}/package.json`;

  return fs.readFile(manifestPath, { encoding: 'utf-8' });

}
```

In the example above, I have to use the `Promise<any>` as a return type. However, is there a better way? Maybe a package published somewhere I can not find?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/package-json-type

```
import {
  IDependencyMap,
  IEngines,
  IPackageJson,
  SPDXLicenseIDApproved
} from 'package-json-type';
 
const dependency: IDependencyMap = {
  bar: '^1.0.0',
  baz: '^2.1.0',
  qux: 'file:../src/qux'
};
 
const engines: IEngines = {
  node: '>=6.0.1 <11.0.0',
  yarn: '^1.15.0',
  zlib: '^0.14.0'
};
 
const license: SPDXLicenseIDApproved = 'MIT';
 
const pkg: IPackageJson = {
  name: 'foo',
  version: '1.2.3',
  dependency,
  description: 'This is awesome foo',
  engines,
  license 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [issue for that in DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/27814). The last comment points to [@schemastore/package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@schemastore/package). The type definitions used there seem correct.

After installing the package, you can use it like this:

```
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';
import {JSONSchemaForNPMPackageJsonFiles} from '@schemastore/package';

export function loadManifest(): Promise<JSONSchemaForNPMPackageJsonFiles> {
  const manifestPath = `${PROJECT_DIR}/package.json`;
  return fs.readFile(manifestPath, { encoding: 'utf-8' }) as Promise<any>;

}
```